# Please help me with this error in simple fizzbuzz program

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

Syntax error near unexpected token 'if'

```
   for x in 1..100 
      if x % 3 == 0
        puts "Fizz"
      elsif (x % 5) == 0
        puts "Buzz"
      else
        puts x
      end
   end
```

Comment: Seems to run OK on [codepad](http://codepad.org/dXKJ1p6C)

Comment: weird, I'm running from Terminal and wrote with sublime text and it's not working.

Comment: Try putting brackets () around the if statement like this: if (x % 3 == 0)

Comment: runs fine here as well. Are you running in IRB by any chance?

Comment: You shouldn't use for loops ruby

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help.   I was running the program incorrectly in the terminal.   (. /  vs 'ruby')